# Checksum of binary changes after rsync-ing to remote machine

Tags: rsync, file-copy, binary, checksum

I'm attempting to copy a binary to a remote machine using rsync, however it appears to corrupt in some way, with both `file` and `md5sum` noting the files difference, rsync on the other hand does not complain at all.

The files are however the same size, and I have also tried scp and sftp.

### Local

```
tmp $ uname -a
Linux dammy 5.10.5-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 07 Jan 2021 09:50:43 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux

tmp $ file vray-benchmark-5.00.01
vray-benchmark-5.00.01: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped

tmp $ md5sum vray-benchmark-5.00.01
a883650ab007ab7cd524ae1a80fb1c84  vray-benchmark-5.00.01
```

Then copied with

```
rsync -a vray-benchmark-5.00.01 joshuao:
```

However have also tried `scp file remote:` and `put` with `sftp`, as well as `--checksum` option with rsync

### Remote

```
josh@joshuao:~$ uname -a
Linux joshuao 4.15.18-25-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.15.18-53 (Wed, 05 Feb 2020 11:58:15 +0100) x86_64 GNU/Linux

josh@joshuao:~$ file vray-benchmark-5.00.01
vray-benchmark-5.00.01: data

josh@joshuao:~$ md5sum vray-benchmark-5.00.01
a41554e0b7ac8ae37e15e83b06a6b45d  vray-benchmark-5.00.01
```

Upon inspection of the files I can see that the file that was copied up to the server are `0` for the first `780140545` bytes, after that the files are the same.

What could be causing this truncation?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Show the `rsync` command you used and the commands you used to check the files together with the corresponding output. What OS do you use?

Comment: Try `--checksum`, i.e. `rsync -a --checksum vray-benchmark-5.00.01 joshuao:` If this doesn't help, copy the bad version back to local with a different name, check that the MD5 is still `a41554e...`, and then see what changed in the file (`cmp --verbose file1.bin file2.bin`).

Comment: `--checksum` didn't change anything, rsync didn't complain about any errors.

The `cmp` ended up complaining a lot, with the file that was copied up and back down being mostly 9s, and then lots of ones.
I'll update my question with an analysis of the file itself.

Comment: So you don't have to reread "Upon inspection of the files I can see that the file that was copied up to the server are 0 for the first 780140545 bytes, after that the files are the same."

Comment: Your local username is also `josh`? Are you copying the correct file from local? (It seems to be in some temporary directory)

Comment: Maybe `cp` and `rsync` the file to other places/systems and check the MD5 hash. Maybe rename the file and `rsync` to the remote again. It's very strange.

Comment: @roaima That is also my local username yes, but I don't know where you're seeing that, I just have different PS1 prompts on the 2 machines, it's definitely the correct file

Comment: The filesystem is intact on `joshuao`, no errors from `dmesg`? No errors reported from the `rsync -avv --checksum vray-benchmark-5.00.01 joshuao:`? On the `total` line at the end it should return non-zero values - if everything is zero then `rsync` is convinced that block by block the two files are the same

Comment: With lots of copying around, I've not managed to reproduce it to any other machine, or on the local filesystem, however it does appear that when copying to "joshuao", it fails in a different way each time. 
Updating question with results of tests.
Any further ideas on how to diagnose this?

Comment: That sounds like a broken disk to me

Comment: Aha, right you are roaima. `dmesg` was absolutely full of errors. The ext4 filesystem is knackered.

Is the ettiquete to post an answer explaining this?

Comment: JoshuaO - yes, it would be helpful if you or @roaima (if he/she is willing) posted the results as an answer. I'm glad you found the source of your problem. *Back up your data now!*

Answer (score 0):

This was in fact a file system issue, as evidenced by various scary logs.

```
$ dmesg
[1651808.506316] Buffer I/O error on device dm-13, logical block 3178496
[1651808.523043] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-13): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 3 writing to inode 140391 (offset 1652555776 size 4096 starting block 3178496)
[1651808.523045] Buffer I/O error on device dm-13, logical block 3178496
[1651808.539230] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-13): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 3 writing to inode 140391 (offset 1652555776 size 4096 starting block 3178496)
[1651808.539232] Buffer I/O error on device dm-13, logical block 3178496
[1651808.554126] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-13): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 3 writing to inode 140391 (offset 1652555776 size 4096 starting block 3178496)
[1651808.554128] Buffer I/O error on device dm-13, logical block 3178496
[1651808.570012] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-13): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 3 writing to inode 140391 (offset 1652555776 size 4096 starting block 3178496)
[1651808.570053] Buffer I/O error on device dm-13, logical block 3178496
[1651808.588767] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-13): ext4_end_bio:323: I/O error 3 writing to inode 140391 (offset 1652555776 size 4096 starting block 3178496)
[1651808.588809] Buffer I/O error on device dm-13, logical block 3178496
```

Upon further inspection, it turned out the disk was simply full, d'oh :)

As well for utility, a command that finally showed that something was indeed awry (other than direct inspection of the file)

```
rsync -avv --checksum vray-benchmark-5.00.01 joshuao:
```